# GridView and empty datasources

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I've got a gridview and I want it to display the header row even if there isn't any data in the collection that it's binding to.

Any ideas on how to do this neatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`<EmptyDataTemplate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx) of the [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control to define a table to be displayed if the data source contains no data. For example

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table class="Standard" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 25%;">
                Header 1</th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">
                Header 2</th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">
                Header 3</th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">
                Header 4`</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 1em; font-style: italic; padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;"
                colspan="4">
                --- No results found ---
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this little function:

```
public static void ShowNoResultFound(DataTable source, GridView gridView)
    {
        DataTable t = source.Clone();
        foreach (DataColumn c in t.Columns)
            c.AllowDBNull = true;
        t.Rows.Add(t.NewRow());
        gridView.DataSource = t;
        gridView.DataBind();
        gridView.Rows[0].Visible = false;
        gridView.Rows[0].Controls.Clear();
    }
```

And then when You get data from sql or another datasource You do this:

```
if (dSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dSet.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    ShowNoResultFound(dSet.Tables[0], GridView1);
}
```